# Is "ages" used only in British English?

Tags: word-usage, british-english

The OALD says that *ages* is, "informal, especially BrE."

Is *ages* as in "I waited for ages" only used in British English?
If it is also used in other English dialects, is there any difference between the usage in those dialects? For example, is *ages* considered informal in one dialect, but not in another one?

Comment: I'm sure people say it here in America, but it sounds British to me anyway.

Comment: What makes you think this trivial metaphor might be more common in UK than US? I have no reason to believe it so.

Comment: Most dictionaries I checked didn't have any such note, but a couple did.  The [Cambridge Advanced Learner’s Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/age_3) says "mainly UK informal".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree. It does not sound at all UK-specific to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any dialect, it is informal when used hyperbolically, as in “I waited for ages”, or “It's been ages since I saw you”.

From [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ages+since+I+saw%2Cwaited+for+ages&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=6&smoothing=3&share=) for *ages since I saw,waited for ages* in a British English corpus, and from similar [ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ages+since+I+saw%2Cwaited+for+ages&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=) in an American English corpus, it's evident that these two expressions are used slightly more frequently in BE than in AE.  I don't recall hearing an American saying something like  “I waited for ages”, but I think I have heard “It's been ages since I saw you” numerous times.

Comment: As a Canadian, I concur that it is more common for me to say, "_I haven't seen you in ages_" than to say, "_I waited for ages_".

Comment: As am American I agree with Trish.  It's not a common phrase but not something that would trigger a double take either.

Comment: I think those NGrams are probably misleading, because there aren't enough instances to draw any safe conclusions. Taking the last few of decades of [been ages since](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=been+ages+since&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=), which is at least 10 times more common (and will almost always be OP's sense), the numbers show it's ***over twice*** as common in America as Britain.

Answer (score 3):

I have heard this type phrase commonly in the US.

> "I waited for ages”

would be inferring a complaint and is not really polite, as in

> "You kept me waiting for ages”.

The focus is on the the person who caused the wait.